# A page for most recent significatly modified questions (not tag-edits) and who has performed it

Tags: feature-request

Editing tags is not adding any information to a question/answers, it is a mainly organizational task. It is not an interesting activity for most users.

It should be possible to see questions sorted based on the time that last significant activity is performed on them. And in place of stating who has performed last activity on the question, it should say who has performed the last significant activity on them.

The main example of **insignificant/uninteresting activity** is *tag edits*, but small edits to questions/answers (like spelling corrections) might also be considered insignificant and uninteresting.

---

I have posted it on SO meta:

[A page for questions sorted based on last significant modification (not tag-edits)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69659/a-page-for-questions-sorted-based-on-last-significant-modification-not-tag-edits)

Comment: Related discussion on Meta Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59428/please-prevent-adding-removing-changing-tags-from-bumping-them-to-the-front-page

Comment: Yea, receiving "updates" via RSS on posts that show "Latest activity: 14 days ago" is not very cool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StackOverflow homepage changes](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/stack-overflow-homepage-changes/).

Answer (score 0):

I think there is one place where bumping questions on tag edits make sense, that is a search including one of the new tags specifically. Otherwise, people looking for this tags (but not for others) might miss the "new" question.

On the main page and in the main feeds they should not be bumped, though.

(I subscribed to Stackoverflow RSS for questions tagged 'scala' only, for example.)